# Aborting the thread from inside the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-abort

I created a thread A and decided to abort it from inside the thread A. Is that possible? If so how can I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
```

Arguably aborting the *current* thread is the only kind of abort that's safe, as it's the only thread you really know about in terms of what it's doing. This is what [`HttpResponse.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) does, for example.

It's not something I would typically recommend - basically it's done because unless you explicitly call [`Thread.ResetAbort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort.aspx), the `ThreadAbortException` will propagate up the call stack regardless of catch blocks - it's a sort of "uber-exception" in that sense.

Comment: Okay, I know it's safe. I'd still look askance at any code that used this. Kind of like seeing a `goto` when there are other, cleaner, ways of doing things. In fact, I've called `Thread.Abort` "the `goto` of multithreaded programming." I'm not 100% set against using `Abort` here, just like I'm not 100% set against using `goto`. But . . .

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes, it's pretty grim - but at least it's better than aborting a *different* thread. Will edit to make it clear that it's not a recommended strategy.